# creat a query string using for loop in c#

Tags: c#, mysql, string, for-loop, append

I'd like to creat a query string wich is generate the right syntax for me!

what i want to achive is like that:

```
select  szallito_nev,
sum(case extract(month from Beerkezes_datuma) when '1' then merlegelt_suly else 0 end) as 'Januar_szall_szly',
sum(case extract(month from Beerkezes_datuma) when '2' then merlegelt_suly else 0 end) as 'Február_szall_szly',
sum(case extract(month from Beerkezes_datuma) when '3' then merlegelt_suly else 0 end) as 'Március_szall_szly',
sum(case extract(month from Beerkezes_datuma) when '4' then merlegelt_suly else 0 end) as 'Április_szall_szly',
sum(case extract(month from Beerkezes_datuma) when '5' then merlegelt_suly else 0 end) as 'Május_szall_szly',
sum(case extract(month from Beerkezes_datuma) when '6' then merlegelt_suly else 0 end) as 'Június_szall_szly',
sum(case extract(month from Beerkezes_datuma) when '7' then merlegelt_suly else 0 end) as 'Július_szall_szly',
sum(case extract(month from Beerkezes_datuma) when '8' then merlegelt_suly else 0 end) as 'Agusztus_szall_szly',
sum(case extract(month from Beerkezes_datuma) when '9' then merlegelt_suly else 0 end) as 'Szeptember_szall_szly',
sum(case extract(month from Beerkezes_datuma) when '10' then merlegelt_suly else 0 end) as 'Október_szall_szly',
sum(case extract(month from Beerkezes_datuma) when '11' then merlegelt_suly else 0 end) as 'November_szall_szly',
sum(case extract(month from Beerkezes_datuma) when '12' then merlegelt_suly else 0 end) as 'December_szall_szly',
sum(merlegelt_suly) as 'Év',
```

and i want to generate the lines from the current mount . For example if its march i want to earn that the loop generate the code to 1-3 and ect..

i will get the current mount nubmer from the

```
string sMonth = DateTime.Now.ToString("MM");
```

and after convert it into integer for the loop

```
 int month = Convert.ToInt32(sMonth);
```

and finaly creat the loop

```
for (int i = 0; i <= month; i++)
        {
            query1 = String.Format(@"select  szallito_nev,
                        sum(case extract(month from Beerkezes_datuma) when '{0}' then merlegelt_suly else 0 end) 
                        as '{1}_szall_szly',",i,i);
        }
```

and i know its not working but is there any way to do this?

Comment: Frankly, since the number of months is pretty rigid, I'd be tempted to just paste in the SQL...

Comment: Rather than `.ToString("MM")` and `Convert.ToInt32` - have you considered using `DateTime.Now.Month` ?

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to say what is not working, but for sure one thing seems wrong, is that 
you have "select  szallito_nev" *inside* loop.

Try something like this:

```
var query = "select  szallito_nev ";
var queryConstructed = new StringBuilder(); 

for (int i = 0; i <= month; i++)
{
  queryConstructed .Append( String.Format(@"sum(case extract(month from Beerkezes_datuma) when '{0}' then merlegelt_suly else 0 end)  as '{1}_szall_szly',",i,i));
}

query  += queryConstructed .ToString();
```

and this *may* resolve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

You need to *append* them:

```
var sql = new StringBuilder("select  szallito_nev,");
for(int i = 1 ; i <= month ; i++)
{
    sql.AppendLine().AppendFormat(
        "sum(case extract(month from Beerkezes_datuma) when '{0}' then merlegelt_suly else 0 end) as '{1}_szall_szly',",
        i, monthName[i-1]);
}
var query = sql.AppendLine().Append("sum(merlegelt_suly) as 'Év',").ToString();
```

Or perhaps better, just `group by` the month instead (this changes the shape of the data, note).

Comment: @balage90 note: having a query that returns different numbers of *columns* is usually confusing; I strongly suggest a `group by` based implementation. Also; you might want to add some `where` clauses to ensure you are querying the correct date range (rather than **every** April, **every** May, etc)

Comment: yes theres a grup by just its missing here i forgot that to write here! its grouped by the szallito_nev `GROUP BY szallito_nev with rollup;`

Comment: @balage90 then why not just group by the month too, and then you don't need to write complex sql...

Comment: how shuld i get the month name for the end of the query ?

Comment: becouse i have to creat a weekly and monthly summary from a big database and i need to transform the tabel into horisontaly. it seems a bit mess but i cant fint other way to do this. and they are based on the companys

Comment: @balage90 in the above? `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.GetMonthName()`